# How to setup the control interface for the Avalon-MM?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, adc, qsys

In QSYS I have an ADC, PLL and an Avalon-MM Read Master to access the internal ADC of the Altera Max10. The control and user interface of the Read Master are exported.

Now I struggle to setup the control interface to access the ADC channels. Mainly following signals:

- control_fixed_location
- control_read_base
- control_read_length

The interface description is:
[image]

The block diagram for the Read Master is:
[image]

**Questions:**
 - How do I need to set the control signals to access the ADC channel x?
 - Where can I find the base address for the ADC implemented in QSYS?

Attached is the quartus archive. Maybe someone can give me an example to simulate this interface in ModelSim.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I have an answer to your second question. I am struggling myself with the first question.

**Where can I find the base address for the ADC implemented in QSYS?**

I know two methods to find the base and end address of a component.
One is to open the **System Contents** view (standard) and scroll to the right side .
*I am not permited to embed images yet.*
There you see a row named Base and End. Here you can find the addresses.

The second method is to open the **Address Map**. Should be located in the same column as System Contents, or you can select View in the top left corner and select it there.
Have a look. You should be able to find it yourself with this information.

What i use when i am searching for examples or prebuild designs is the altera website. Here a link for you https://cloud.altera.com/devstore/platform/

Probably you like this one: https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_adc.pdf

The configuration is complete in QSYS? Like selecting channels and Sequencer in your ADC Block. Selecting the right input clocks and the right frequencies?

You wrote: 
**In QSYS I have an ADC, PLL and an Avalon-MM Read Master to access the internal ADC of the Altera Max10. The control and user interface of the Read Master are exported.**

Have you created a clock for your PLL? When i want to simulate a clock signal for a QSYS system i export the clock signals and define the wanted clock in an additional file.

When you go one step further and include a nios2 processor i recommend to have a look at the altera_modular_adc.c file.

*edit

If you haven't assigned any base addresses there is a function in QSYS which does the job for you.

In System (Same column as File) -> Assign Base Addresses